# ColourScale ForceNetwork (NetworkD3) in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets, networkd3

In forcenetwork, i found group and colourscale to colour the node in a network. I would like to have 2 different groups(colour is applied to the node based on user input between 2 different variables). Is it possible to have it? If yes, how?

Forcenetwork - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/networkD3/versions/0.4/topics/forceNetwork

Any kind of help will be useful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `colourScale` parameter determines the color palette, while the `group` parameter determines the name of the vector in your nodes data frame that contains values to distinguish the group of each node. `networkD3` automatically chooses a unique color from the color palette for each distinct group in your data and applies that color to each node in that group.

```
library(networkD3)

links <- read.table(header = T, text = "
source  target  value
0       1       1
1       2       1
2       0       1
0       3       1
3       4       1
4       5       1
5       3       1
")

nodes <- read.table(header = T, text = "
name    group
zero    1
one     1
two     1
three   2
four    2
five    2
")

forceNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, 
             Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value", 
             NodeID = "name", Group = "group", 
             colourScale = JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);"))
```

If you have two separate variables in your data that jointly determine the group of each node, you should combine them in your data before passing them to `forceNetwork()`...

```
nodes <- read.table(header = T, text = "
name    group1  group2
zero    A       D
one     B       E
two     C       F
three   A       E
four    B       F
five    C       D
")

nodes$group <- paste(nodes$group1, nodes$group2, sep = "_")

forceNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, 
             Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value", 
             NodeID = "name", Group = "group", 
             colourScale = JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);"))
```

Comment: Yeah. I know this. Can i have more than one group? something like Group = c("group1", "group2")

Comment: There are two groups in my example: group “1” and group “2”.

Comment: I clarified the explanation of the group parameter in my answer... maybe that was causing confusion?